# Pass dynamic title to route in ex-navigation used in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ex-navigation

I am using a single component for handling multiple tasks(say, Bring the food/Clean the room).I pass task title as props to the component and it renders accordingly.This component will be called with different props multiple times.I am using ex-navigation to render my navigation bar in my task component as follows:

```
    static route = {
      navigationBar: {
        backgroundColor: '#0096ff',
        tintColor: '#fff',
        title: 'Clean' //Need to do make this dynamic based on props value
      }
    }
```

Now I want title to be dynamic and be using value from the props (title:this.props.title). Now since this is a static variable, how can I use props value (which only comes after constructor is initialised) in the static routes variable to make my title dynamic based on props passed to the component.

Answer (score 2):

`title` property within **navigationBar** can be a `function` receiving params as an argument like so

```
title(params) {
        return `Greeting for ${params.name}`;
      },
```

check https://github.com/exponent/ex-navigation#passing-params-to-a-route
for more way of doing it

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using redux and you have configured `ex-navigator` to work with it, you should have `navigator` as a prop. When you push your main route you can pass the title that you want:

`this.props.navigator.push(Router.getRoute('MainRoute', {title: 'WhateverYouWant'}))`

As it is your main route and you will reuse it, you can update the title `udateCurrentRouteParams()`.

```
     this.props.navigator.updateCurrentRouteParams({
      title: 'NewTitle',
    })
```